# Getting "ESP_TLS Error : empty esp_tls parameter" Error

Tags: esp8266, esp-idf

I am using the simple_ota_example :

https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/tree/master/examples/system/ota/simple_ota_example

Here is my code :

My .bin is sent as a response from the URL : https://www.website.com/get-firmware

```
void simple_ota_example_task(void * pvParameter)
{


    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Starting OTA example...");

    esp_http_client_config_t ota_config = {
        .url = "https://www.website.com/get-firmware",
        .cert_pem = (char *)server_cert_pem_start,
        .event_handler = _http_event_handler,
        .auth_type = HTTP_AUTH_TYPE_NONE,
        .port = 80
    };

    esp_err_t ret = esp_https_ota(&ota_config);
    if (ret == ESP_OK) {
        esp_restart();
    } else {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Firmware Upgrades Failed");
    }


    while (1) {
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }


}

void ota_main(){
     xTaskCreate(&simple_ota_example_task, "ota_example_task", 8192, NULL, 5, NULL);
}
```

The error I receive is :

E (13369) esp-tls: empty esp_tls parameter
E (13375) esp-tls: Failed to open new connection
E (13383) TRANS_SSL: Failed to open a new connection

What is causing this issue? Will appreciate any help.

The error comes from the esp_tls.c file :

```
static int esp_tls_low_level_conn(const char *hostname, int hostlen, int port, const esp_tls_cfg_t *cfg, esp_tls_t *tls)
{
    if (!tls) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "empty esp_tls parameter");
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: `tls` seems not to be set. See documentation here: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/esp_tls.html

Comment: Thanks, I have added esp_tls_init() before the task is created, in the ota_main() function. But still getting errors : 

E (301536) esp-tls-mbedtls: mbedtls_x509_crt_parse returned -0x2780
E (301538) esp-tls-mbedtls: Failed to set client configurations
E (301542) esp-tls: create_ssl_handle failed
E (301550) esp-tls: Failed to open new connection
E (301558) TRANS_SSL: Failed to open a new connection
E (301569) HTTP_CLIENT: Connection failed, sock < 0
E (301575) esp_https_ota: Failed to open HTTP connection: 28674
E (301585) simple_ota_example: Firmware Upgrades Failed